# Varchar scalar function using decimals returns only int

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-function

I am banging my head on this one. If I execute this

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar, CONVERT(datetime, 0.55), 108);
```

I get "13:12:00".

However, placing this into a scalar function as so

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[t_ExcelToTime] (@Excel decimal (12,8))
RETURNS varchar
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Result varchar
    SELECT @Result =  CONVERT(varchar,CONVERT(datetime, @Excel), 108)
    RETURN @Result
END
```

And calling it as

```
SELECT [dbo].[t_ExcelToTime](0.55);
```

returns "1"

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Never declare a `varchar` without a size! `DECLARE varchar` is the same as `DECLARE varchar(1);`. Thus, that is the return value you get.

Comment: You;re returning varchar with no precision

Comment: Thank you both for the responses. It's funny that CONVERT does not require this when used inline, that's what was tripping me up.

Comment: It isn't that it doesn't require it. The difference is that a parameter has a default size of 1, but inline it has a default of 30. This is why it is so critical to specify the size of every varchar. I wish the t-sql syntax did require the size in all situations to avoid this kind of thing.

Comment: `varchar` doesn't require length declaration *anywhere*. Please read: https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"returns varchar" is the same as "returns varchar(1)". Give your datatype an appropriate length.

Comment: <Facepalm>. Thank you very much!